# Bulk rename files with only one common factor in the middle with CMD or Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

Okay so a bit of a weird one but I have files with names like file_ytd.test.dds, file2_ytd.test.dds, file3_ytd.test.dds, file_ytd.notatest.dds

and I want to rename them so that they are

test.dds, notatest.dss

and of course it removes the duplicates I wanted to use this command in powershell, but I would need to manually type out the full name for each "file_ytd." type, and I have about 100k different variations in 400k files

````
``` Dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "file_ytd." ""} ```
````

What would be the best way about this?

Comment: If you rename both `file2_ytd.test.dds` and `file3_ytd.test.dds` you'll end up with 2 files named `test.dds` - how do you want to handle that conflict?

Comment: I should have been more specific but I essentially want to either remove all of the conflicts in the process or if required I could rename them any with a conflict as `test.dds_copy0` `test.dds_copy1` and so on and then just remove all the copies when I'm done through windows explorer.

Comment: "and then just remove all the copies when I'm done through windows explorer" - so you'd rather just skip them? Only keep the first file in each set of conflicting file names?

Comment: Exactly, as all of the ones with a repeating name after `_ytd.` are the exact same file with a different name at the start

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correclty, t his would do the trick.

`-WhatIf` parameter added to both `Rename-Item` and `Remove-Item` so you can see if it's doing what you want.

```
Get-ChildItem |
 select fullName , @{N='NewName';E={$_.BaseName.Split('.')[-1]+$_.Extension}} |
 group NewName | foreach {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Group[0].FullName -NewName $_.Name -WhatIf
    If ($_.Count -gt 1)
    {
        $_.Group[1..($_.Count -1)].FullName | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: So I had a look at and ran this script and I understand what its doing, pretty much grabbing the '.' in the file name and performing almost exactly what I want, with a need for a bit of play from me only issue is when I run this script on my test folder, it tells me it performs the actions but does nothing, are there some errors we have both missed?

Comment: That's the `-WhatIf` parameter I put in for "protection" from accidental deletion while testing. You have to delete `-WhatIf` from *both* the `Rename-Item` and `Remove-Item` cmdlet for the actions to actually take place.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have much experience with this so its all a little confusing, works great tho

Comment: No worries...if all is working, please mark my reply as `Answer`...Thanks....

Comment: Please consider marking this as answer as the `solution` to the question.